# Sieve function in QGIS not working properly?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, pixel

I am trying to eliminate single pixels in a (binary) raster with the gdal_sieve function. However, regardless of the settings I choose (I tried threshold=1, 2 and 70 and pixel connection 8), the result is identical to the original raster.
Any insight on this issue?

Comment: Test data would be appreciated.